# How do I fix problem with layout of tables and text in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

my problem is that my full tables and text are coming about 15 cm away from left side,
so my text has very little space on right side, about 3 cm.

How can I change my text and tables to start from 5 cm away from left and 5 cm before right side?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}      
\usepackage{graphics} 
\usepackage{color}                  
\usepackage{hyperref}              
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\oddsidemargin 0cm
\evensidemargin 0cm

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\lfoot{%(full_name)s/%(emp_id)s/\thepage}
\cfoot{}

\topmargin -2.5cm
\parindent 0cm
\textheight 27.5cm
\parskip 3mm

\begin{document}

\fontencoding{\encodingdefault}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\fontshape{\shapedefault}
\selectfont
```

Thanks

Comment: Use the layout package to see what margins are in effect: http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/tools/layout.pdf

Comment: A quick answer is just to `\usepackage{fullpage}`.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to have a look at the [geometry package](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf).

This package can be used in the following way for instance:

```
\usepackage[left=1in]{geometry}.
```